# Android align set of buttons programatically in layout

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment, android-button

the thing which I want to achieve in my application is to create dynamically a set of buttons with different text size and after that align these view inside a linear layout. Here is a sample of what I want to achieve :

[image] . Depending on the textsize I want the buttons to be align in a single line, if the last button is bigger than the screen size, it should properly go to the next line.

Any suggestions how can I achieve this or what should I look for, because I know that if I try `button.getWidth();` it will return 0 and it won't work.

Thanks for any kind of suggestions!

**EDIT**

### **To achieve this you can use a new layout open sources by Google called: [FlexboxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout). You can learn more about it in this [post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/02/build-flexible-layouts-with.html) from Android Developers Blog.**

Comment: Try to use custom horizontal ListView.

Comment: take a look at http://www.androidviews.net/2012/11/chips-text-fields/ maybe this might help. Am too reading its code in the mean time.

Comment: can you provide the code for above displayed screen shot. if you have i'm looking for that solution text width based dynamical buttons

Comment: @VenkateshNani I think this will work for you: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/02/build-flexible-layouts-with.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following
While adding the buttons you can calculate the how much width till occupied as

```
occupiedWidth = button1Width + button2Width + ...
```

Every button width = textWidth + 2*margin + 2*padding

You can get your width of the text which you put on the button like

```
String buttonText = "<Your Button Text>"
paint.getTextBounds(buttonText, 0, buttonText.length(), bounds);
int textWidth = bounds.width();
```

Add this new button margins and paddings as

```
int newWidth = textWidth + buttonMargin*2 + buttonPadding*2;
```

if the total width is exceeding the screenwidth then move to next row.

Comment: thanks for giving me a direction of how to get the text size. this helped me to find the right direction to do it, so I will accept your answer as the correct one!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Kameswari 's code which gave me the right direction I achieve this by using :

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);

String[] mKeywordsArray = mKeywords.split(", ");
if(mKeywordsArray != null){

    LinearLayout mNewLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity()); // Horizontal layout which I am using to add my buttons.
    mNewLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    int mButtonsSize = 0;
    Rect bounds = new Rect();

    for(int i = 0; i < mKeywordsArray.length; i++){

        String mButtonTitle = mKeywordsArray[i];
        Button mBtn = new Button(getActivity());
        mBtn.setPadding(10, 3, 10, 3);
        mBtn.setText(mButtonTitle);

        Paint textPaint = mBtn.getPaint();
        textPaint.getTextBounds(mButtonTitle, 0, mButtonTitle.length(), bounds);
            // size of all buttons in current horizontal layout
            // i am using +45 because of extra padding which is set in xml for this layout
        mButtonsSize += ( bounds.width() + 45);
        if(mButtonsSize < (mScreenWidth - 32)){ // -32 because of extra padding in main layout.
            mNewLayout.addView(mBtn, params);
        } else {
            mButtonsLayout.addView(mNewLayout);
            mNewLayout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            mNewLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            mButtonsSize = bounds.width();
            mNewLayout.addView(mBtn, params); // add button to a new layout so it won't be stretched because of it's width.
        }

    }

    mButtonsLayout.addView(mNewLayout); // add the last layout/ button.
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more pls. I have to achieve the same conndition but i have no idea how to do this thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to me, you have 2 options:

1) Take a `linear layout` with `horizontal` orientation.
and keep adding buttons to this layout programmatically.
if the width of the button is not able to fit in the line, it will automatically go to next line in linear layout.

```
ViewGroup linearLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutID);

Button bt = new Button(this);
bt.setText("A Button");
bt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
linerLayout.addView(bt);
```

2) You can calculate x,y location of each button as mentioned by @kameswari and draw corresponding button at x,y location

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);// or new Button(this);
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams absParams = 
    (AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams)button.getLayoutParams();
absParams.x = X;
absParams.y = Y;
button.setLayoutParams(absParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
u can try this `enter code here`

 LinearLayout.LayoutParams leftMarginParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        leftMarginParams.leftMargin = 50;

        Button btn1 = new Button(this);
        btn1.setText("Button1");
        linLayout.addView(btn1, leftMarginParams)
```